# DVDauthor parameter

Tags: video, dvd

I want to create a video dvd.
containing about 20 clips.  I don't want them to be merged to only one 
vob-file.
I want to keep all 20 vob files to access the later easy by copying the corresponding clip.

I don't want any menu. The first clip should have the option autostart.
After the first clip automatically the next clips should be played.
The Next and Previous buttons should behave as they would on an audio cd.

When I use the following commands a DVD is created containing 20 titles and the 20 vob files are kept, like I want, but only this first is played.
I can access the others using the DVD/Blue-ray Player's Menu.  But the Prev/Next Buttons are not working.

```
dvdauthor -o /tmp/dvd -t 01_01.vob
dvdauthor -o /tmp/dvd -t 02_01.vob
...
dvdauthor -o /tmp/dvd -t 20_01.vob
dvdauthor -o /tmp/dvd -T 
mkisofs -dvd-video -o /media/andreas/VOB/dvd.iso /tmp/dvd/
```

All other tools would combine the 20 vobs to one vob.  I don't like this, because it means on later days, if I need only one clip again, 
I would have to cut this clip again, instead only copying the vob clip.

What should I change to have all features I want?